# FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster Unhandled exception. Starting shutdown

Tags: apache, hadoop, hbase, cluster-computing, cloudera

I have 4 nodes CentOS hadoop cluster. I installed cloudera manager 5.5.1.

I failed to start Hbase Master.

> FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster Unhandled exception.
>   Starting shutdown

.

> Caused by:
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException):
>   Permission denied: user=hbase, access=WRITE,
>   inode="/":hdfs:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x

Any thoughts?

Thanks